# Best approach for Sql.Open Global connection

Tags: go

I'm trying to create a global DB sql.Open connection between multiple .go packages.
Doing this will allow me to key in my DB connection only once instead of doing it multiple times between separate files.

I've created this file so far:

```
import (
    "database/sql"
)

var DB *sql.DB

func ConnectDB() {
    db, _ := sql.Open("mysql", "user:password@(localhost:port)/db")

    DB = db
}
```

I'm assigning my connection to the global variable DB. I know that I could use DB.query or otherpkg.DB.
I can avoid the DB = db by not using the := and doing, the := assign a new variable into the function's scope:

```
var db *sql.DB

func ConnectDB() {
  var err error
  db, err = sql.Open(.....)
  .....
}
```

My other files look like the following:

```
func TestNew() {
    fmt.Println("Test for MySQL")

    db, _ := sql.Open(
        "mysql", "user:password@(localhost:port)/db")

    Delete, err := db.Query("DELETE * FROM table1 WHERE id = ?;", id)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer Delete.Close()
}
```

I don't want to go into each separate file inside of my packages and change the DB credentials 10x. I'd like to use the **func ConnectDB** and have that be the file which controls what DB/credentials are used for the other packages.

Comment: First off, there's no reason to use a _global_ here, but that doesn't really seem to be related to your question. Just pass your single db instance into the other methods/constructors that need it. Classic dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

A common way of doing this is initializing the connection in main, and passing it down to all the functions that need it.

Another way of doing it is to use a package other than main, and set a package level variable there:

```
package db

var DB *sql.DB

func InitDB(dbURL string) {
  var err error
  DB, err=sql.Open(dbURL)
  if err!=nil {
    panic(err)
  }
}
```

You call `InitDB` from `main` with the DB URL. When you need the DB connection, you import the db package, and use the connection as `db.DB`.